# How do I manually create an $_FILES file object?

Tags: php, file

I'm hacking Chamilo so it automatically imports an iCal file when the user views their personal agenda. So far I've been able to pin-point the functions that I need to call in order to make this happen.

However, the function that does the actual importing expects a reference to a file object from the `$_FILES` superglobal. It gets the file name from `$file['tmp_name']` and calls `file_get_contents()` on it.

I've thought about duplicating the function and altering it so it expects a regular file object, but that seems a poor way of handling it. A better solution would be to construct the file object that it expects. But I have no idea how to do that, and googling hasn't helped.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5):

If the library is well-written, this will not be possible - even if you construct an artificial `$_FILES` array, you can't fool `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()`. Those will explicitly check whether the file passed was actually uploaded. (There was a security hole once, a long time ago, that exploited this. AFAIK, the `_uploaded_file()` functions were introduced in response to that.)

You can try and build a `$_FILES` array with the correct values - you can see the expected structure [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

If that doesn't work (as said above, it shouldn't), you'll have no choice but to alter the library. In my eyes, that's the cleaner way, anyway.